# nginx parllel uploading issue form submission

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04, hhvm

I have an php web app that buils on laravel5. i use nginx. in my website there is an contact form where user can upload multiple files . My issue is whenever user uploading multiple files its not uploading instead its showing loading for very long time. if upload single file then its uploading instantly. i'm not sure why exactly

```
OS: ubuntu 14.04 x64
nginx/1.8.0 , PHP 5.6.14-1
```

any suggestions ?

nginx.conf :

```
              `
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
proxy_send_timeout  600s;
proxy_read_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 512m;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;
##
# Gzip Settings
##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;

          `
```

sites-enabled default.conf :

```
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 140;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 400;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 400;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
```

Comment: you getting any error looking at the console? maybe you get error from laravel because of  CSRF and your js get some error

Comment: no errors in console .. if i upload single file its working .. if uploading multiple files request even not  going to server

Comment: Can you show piece of backend php code of upload files?

Comment: actually not possible .. its simple laravel form

Comment: If your upload form exist in a nested table, multiple upload may not work.

Answer (score 0):

For first -- sorry for my bad English, oh Globish ))

You cant give more info. But I try explain.

If you want upload single file:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file">
```

and for backend:

```
$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_file']
```

If you want upload multiple files: IMPORTANT! This two cases!

Case one (i presume this is your current case):

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file[]">
```

and for backend:

```
$_FILES['upload_file'][$arrKey]['tmp_file']
```

Case two:

```
<input type="file" name="upload_file" multiple="multiple">
```

and for backend:

```
$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_file']
```

Look for case two -- backend code equivalent for single upload.
How it works?
Because browser send multiple files with separated requests, one file per request. And you can show upload status for all files and/or for current uploading file.

Comment: Actually in my question is  In a form, multiple files can be uploaded to a single file field but can we submit two file fields in same form to server at the same instance?
 
I have tried it and server it not accepting both requests at the same time.